# Word Embedding from BERT to Machine Learning Model Accuracy is not good

Tags: python, bert-language-model, word-embedding, machine-learning-model

I am trying solving a product matching task by extracting the word embedding from BERT and feed the word embedding to Machine Learning models.

However, the accuracy is not good.

I tried different truncation strategy and use single attribute or concatenated 2 attributes as the input for the word embedding, but the accuracy did not improve a lot.

May you pls suggest me what should I do to improve the performance of the models?

Here is the project in github
https://github.com/jajawong/Data-Science/blob/main/Copy_of_FineTuneBert_Feature_Extraction%20(1).ipynb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't link to your repository. Include the relevant code here in the question, as a [mcve]. Your repository may change, or get deleted, and then the question is useless for others with the same problem. Also be more precise with the problem description. What do you mean by "not good" and "did not improve a lot"? See also [ask].